# Retrieve sessionStorage data on new page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, web-storage

js web storage newbie here.

I'm working on a billing page for a Wordpress site.

This page needs to show the items that a user has added to the cart on the previous (checkout page).

I have saved a new entry in the session storage database to show items in a user's cart like so :

```
setStorage_(data) {
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('tbhCart', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

**How can I retrieve this data & display it on the next page (billing page)?**

Comment: `sessionStorage.getItem('tbhCart')` Just curious, did you really not try Google for "sessionStorage" before posting this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getItem()` on `sessionStorage`.

```
var tbhCart = sessionStorage.getItem("tbhCart");
```

Answer (score 0):

simple answer would be

```
sessionStorage.getItem('youritem');
```

Hope it helps.